# Selenium RC slower on Windows 7 than on XP?

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, selenium

I've got two systems, one with Windows XP and another with 7, both running Firefox 3.6, the same version of Selenium RC and the newest nunit.

When I run tests on 7, it is executed extremely slowly (I mean walking by textbox and setting its values), but when I execute this script on Windows XP it is extremely fast.

Do you have the same experience? Do you know what the problem might be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We run all our tests in Windows 7, so I can't accurately compare it to execution on Windows XP, but I would not describe what we are seeing as executing "extremely slowly". The slowest part of any of our tests is waiting for our staging environment to respond, everything else seems pretty fast. Hope that helps.